# Как добавить в C#-проект dll-файл?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В одном из классов я использую написанную на C++ dll-библиотеку:

```
[DllImport("excample.dll", EntryPoint = "_foo@4")]
private static extern int foo();
```

Не хотелось бы руками добавлять dll сначала в папки bin/Release и bin/Debug, а потом ещё и в такие же папки проекта с юнит-тестами.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ по типу добавления в ссылки, чтобы студия автоматически подхватила зависимости?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Добавляешь в проект как обычный файл, выделяешь его и в Properties есть какой-то пункт (точно не помню) типа "что делать с файлом при компиляции". Варианты: ничего, компилировать, копировать неизменно (и мот ещё что есть). Выставить копирование и он будет копироваться:)

ps: пардон за неконкретику, под рукой только notepad =)

Comment: Только есть одна подстава с этим способом, которую в свое время не смог быстро решить. При добавлении такой ДЛЛ НЕ в корень проекта, а в папку, она будет копироваться в БИН в такой же папке (...\bin\folder\lib.dll). То есть, если вы расчитуете, что данная ДЛЛ будет именно в бине без поддиректорий, то и в проект необходимо добавлять именно в корень. Знаете решение, поделитеь плз.

Answer (score 2):

В Solution Explorer(Обозреватель решений), есть папка Reference(ссылки), нажимаете правой кнопкой -> Добавить -> Browse -> выбираете, и библиотека добавится в ваш проект.

Comment: «Не удаётся добавить ссылку на "…". Убедитесь, что файл доступен, и является допустимой сборкой или компонентом COM.»

Comment: Хм... странно, а вы нажали именно Browse, а не COM?

Comment: Да, именно Browse. Подозреваю накладываются какие-то ограничения на dll'ки, подключаемые таким образом. Ибо с тестовой скомпилированной мною dll'кой ваш способ корректно работает.

Comment: Данный способ не прокатит с ДЛЛ на плюсах.

Comment: @wind, только что проверил на «библиотеке классов» — работает.

Comment: @Jofsey, проверяю на ДЛЛ с винапишными ф-циями и хз чем еще, к-ю использую часто, а именно User32.dll из систем32 - не добавляется таким макаром.