# Подключение C++ dll к WPF проекту C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

Есть WPF проект на C# и С++ dll реализующая некоторые сложные вычисления, возможно ли как то подключить эту библиотеку к С# проекту для создания экземпляров классов С++, и если да, то что для этого требуется? Если не сложно объясните поэтапно, я в этом деле новичок.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить в C#-проект dll-файл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76365/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-dll-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать именно классы `c++`, то вариант решения, примерно такой:

1. Объявим класс который будет `generic` классом:

```
public abstract class CClassBase<TNewDelegate, TDeleteDelegate> :
    IDisposable
    where TNewDelegate    : Delegate
    where TDeleteDelegate : Delegate
{
    protected TNewDelegate    New;
    protected TDeleteDelegate Delete;
    protected IntPtr          ThisPtr;

    protected CClassBase(TNewDelegate newDelegate, TDeleteDelegate deleteDelegate)
    {
        New = newDelegate;
        Delete = deleteDelegate;
    }

    public bool IsDisposed
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    protected abstract void Dispose(bool disposable);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~CClassBase()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

2. Наследование от этого класса, базового класса, не `generic`:

```
// Делегат конструктора без параметров, вы можете определять свои, и наследоваться от generic класса
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
public delegate void NewDelegate(ref IntPtr thisPtr);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
public delegate void DeleteDelegate(ref IntPtr thisPtr);
```

```
public class CClassBase :
    CClassBase<NewDelegate, DeleteDelegate>
{
    protected CClassBase(NewDelegate newDelegate, DeleteDelegate deleteDelegate)
        : base(newDelegate, deleteDelegate)
    {
        New(ref ThisPtr);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposable)
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        Delete(ref ThisPtr);

        if (disposable)
        {
            ThisPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            New = null;
            Delete = null;
        }

        IsDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

3. Описание неуправляемого (экспортируемого класса) класса:

В моем случае неуправляемый класс объявлен как:

```
struct MI_CORE_API engine : public ::window_container
{
public:
    ::LRESULT on_message(::HWND hwnd, ::UINT msg, ::WPARAM w_param, ::LPARAM l_param) override;
    bool process_messages() override;
    bool initialize(::HINSTANCE app_instance, ::int32_t width, ::int32_t height, wchar_t const* application_name);
};
```

Соответственно я определил управляемый класс как:

```
public class Engine :
    CClassBase
{
    [DllImport("mi_core.dll",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall,
        EntryPoint = "??0engine@@QAE@XZ")]
    private static extern void EngineNew(ref IntPtr thisPtr);

    [DllImport("mi_core.dll",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall,
        EntryPoint = "??1engine@@UAE@XZ")]
    private static extern void EngineDelete(ref IntPtr ptr);

    [DllImport("mi_core.dll",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall,
        EntryPoint = "?initialize@engine@@QAE_NPAUHINSTANCE__@@HHPB_W@Z")]
    private static extern bool EngineInitialize(ref IntPtr thisPtr, IntPtr applicationInstance, int width, int height,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string applicationName);

    [DllImport("mi_core.dll",
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall,
        EntryPoint = "?process_messages@engine@@UAE_NXZ")]
    private static extern bool EngineProcessMessages(ref IntPtr thisPtr);

    public Engine() :
        base(EngineNew, EngineDelete)
    {
        GC.KeepAlive(this);
    }

    public bool ProcessMessages()
    {
        return EngineProcessMessages(ref ThisPtr);
    }

    public bool Initialize(int width, int height, string applicationName)
    {
        ProcessModule processModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;

        if (processModule == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        IntPtr applicationInstance = processModule.BaseAddress;
        return EngineInitialize(ref ThisPtr, applicationInstance, width, height, applicationName);

    }
}
```

Ну и запуск:

```
internal static class Program
{

    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Engine engine = new Engine())
        {
            if (!engine.Initialize(1280, 720, "Some Application Name"))
            {
                return 1;
            }

            while (engine.ProcessMessages())
            {
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]